Update view in Tandem viewer
i have created a tandem viewer in next js and fetched all the views in twin-models with
const data = await fetch(`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/tandem/v1/twins/${twinId}/views`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: await this.getAuthHeader(),
        },
      }).then((response: any) => response.json());

but unable to update the view from the listing can anyone help.
I'm trying to update the view by selecting one of the view from the listing

to display specific saved view in the viewer you can use DtApp.views.setCurrentView method. For example following snippet shows how to set current view to the one named "Test":
const views = await app.views.fetchFacilityViews(facility);
const view = views.find(v => v.viewName === 'Test');

if (view) {
  await app.views.setCurrentView(facility, view);
}


You can see this in the React sample for embedded viewer.
